# Synchronize block pinning virtual thread

Tags: java, project-loom

I am an enthusiast and am wondering about virtual threads. In the docs it says that one of the conditions to pin the thread is in a synchronized block, and in those cases to use a semaphore. Here are the docs to the JEP https://openjdk.org/jeps/444

> There are two scenarios in which a virtual thread cannot be unmounted during blocking operations because it is pinned to its carrier:
> When it executes code inside a synchronized block or method, or
> When it executes a native method or a foreign function.

Is this due to the implementation of a synchronized block being a spin lock and the thread does not stop executing instructions, while a semaphore will yield after a few attempts?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a link to the docs you are referring to.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No, this is just that synchronized is implemented in the JVM, while a semaphore is implemented in Java (which sees that you use a virtual thread and yields instead of blocking).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [JEP 425](https://openjdk.org/jeps/425) gives, in my opinion, more detailed technical information on the issue you raised. It mentions `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock`. A synchronization primitive `Semaphore` also exists in Java Concurrency and it uses the same `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` a.k.a. the AQS as `ReentrantLock` does, so it is conceptually the same, but semantic of `ReentrantLock` is very similar to that of `synchronized` block, which is advised to be replaced. But this is a technical remark.

The key difference is that `ReentrantLock`, AQS, direct `Unsafe`/`VarHandle` and similar synchronization primitives use non-blocking CAS technique while `synchronized` blocks the thread, at least in a case of contention.

To understand the difference between the two, I'd advise to learn more about [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) and/or experiment with Java `Atomic*` methods `compareAndSet`.

As a side note, `ReentrantLock`, AQS and few other other synchronization primitives still may block the thread (in fact, it is necessary, generally speaking), it is done by calling `LockSupport.park` methods. Under the hood, `LockSupport.park` also invokes a native method, but for some reason this is not (or lesser?) problem for Virtual Threads.