# Java 21 virtual threads and Guava striped locks replacement

Tags: java, guava, java-threads

Striped locks, as popularized with Google Guava java library, allow the user to trade between required concurrency and memory footprint. However, I wonder if this is still true with Java 21 virtual threads? Also, are there are alternatives to Guava `Striped<L>` class (preferably java code depending on Java alone)? I do not want to add dependency to Guava just for this.

**UPDATE**: I am considering Guava "striped locks" replacement code like this - any opinions?

```java
import java.lang.ref.Reference;
import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;

public class StripedLocks {

    private final int stripes;
    private final transient ReferenceQueue<LockHolder> queue;
    private final transient ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, WeakReference<LockHolder>> locks;

    public StripedLocks(int stripes) {
        this.stripes = stripes;
        queue = new ReferenceQueue<>();
        locks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    public StripedLocks() {
        this(4);
    }

    public final <T> T read(Object keyObject, Callable<T> readOperation) throws Exception {
        return execute(getLock(keyObject).readLock(), readOperation);
    }

    public final <T> T write(Object keyObject, Callable<T> writeOperation) throws Exception {
        return execute(getLock(keyObject).writeLock(), writeOperation);
    }

    private ReentrantReadWriteLock getLock(Object keyObject) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(keyObject,"keyObject can't be null");
        var key = keyObject.hashCode() % stripes;
        return locks.compute(key, (_, currentReference) -> {
            if(currentReference==null)
                return new WeakReference<>(new LockHolder(key, new ReentrantReadWriteLock()), queue);
            var lockHolder = currentReference.get();
            if (lockHolder == null)
                return new WeakReference<>(new LockHolder(key, new ReentrantReadWriteLock()), queue);
            return currentReference;
        }).get().lock();
    }

    private <T> T execute(Lock theLock, Callable<T> operation) throws Exception {
        theLock.lock();
        try {
            return operation.call();
        } finally {
            theLock.unlock();
            purgeStaleLocks();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    void purgeStaleLocks() {
        Reference<LockHolder> reference;
        while ((reference = (Reference<LockHolder>) queue.poll()) != null) {
            synchronized (queue) {
                locks.remove(reference.get().key());
            }
        }
    }

    private record LockHolder(int key, ReentrantReadWriteLock lock) {}

}
```

Comment: Seems like you can use Guava as it is. This thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76618264/synchronize-block-pinning-virtual-thread saying Fibers e.g. Virtual threads synchronization based on java.util.concurrent.locks  As well as Guava build on top of it https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.java

Comment: Yes, it would still have the same value and effects.